# $\left|x_{2}\right|-\left|x_{1}\right| \leq\left|x_{2}-x_{1}\right|$ looks like the reverse triangle inequality but is not?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not sure whether I have caught a typo/mistake in my textbook or not.

It states the triangle inequality for real numbers:
$\left|x_{0}+x_{1}\right| \leq\left|x_{0}\right|+\left|x_{1}\right|$. The author says define $x_0 := x_2-x_1$ then $\left|x_{2}\right|-\left|x_{1}\right| \leq\left|x_{2}-x_{1}\right|$. But shouldn't this be $\left| \left|x_{2}\right|-\left|x_{1}\right| \right| \leq\left|x_{2}-x_{1}\right|$ which is the reverse triangle inequality?

Kind regards

Comment: May I know the book name, author, edition, and page No.?

Comment: Well, this version follows from the reverse triangle inequality. A real number is not bigger than its absolute value, so $|x_2-x_1|\geq ||x_2|-|x_1||\geq |x_2|-|x_1|$.

Answer (score 2):

$$|x_2|=|x_2-x_1+x_1|\stackrel{\text{trian. ineq.}}\le|x_2-x_1|+|x_1|\implies |x_2|-|x_1|\le|x_2-x_1|$$

and the book is right: that inequality follows from the triangle's.

Answer (score 0):

$|x_2|-|x_1|\leq ||x_2|-|x_1|| $ is true in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse triangle inequality is indeed 
$$||x_2|-|x_1|| \leqslant |x_2-x_1|. $$
Recall that the absolute inequality $|x| \leqslant a$ with $a \geqslant 0$ is equivalent to the pair
$$-a \leqslant x \leqslant a. $$
Hence the reverse triangle inequality is equivalent to
$$(-|x_2-x_1| \leqslant)|x_2|-|x_1| \leqslant |x_2-x_1| .$$
In other words, the author's inequality is a consequence of the true reverse triangle inequality.